# Why does my websites loads js file with old content?

Tags: javascript, php, firefox

I've edited an js script, which replace some specific HTML tags with the new language (german -> englisch, englisch -> german). It works for some steps as it should work but immediately the website didn't do the right thing. Firebug tells me that the js script has it's old content before I edited it.

There isn't any other file with this same name. I deleted my complete history, cache, etc. What's the reason the old content of the js script is alive?

Sometimes if I deleted the lang.js file deleted history and cache, etc. the website still works. Why is there a lang.js file?

Comment: How do you serve this page?

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the following

```
1. Clear the cache of the browser.
2. Do a clean build of the Webapp
```

OR

Open the Browser in InCognito or Private Browsing Mode

OR

Try to put a meta tag in your HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Comment: Private Browsing Mode does the same, Clear cache und a clean build the same. Meta tag still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times it is browser side caching. That said, sometimes it isn't. If what Jubair said doesn't work:

1. If you use CDN, you might have to purge it.
2. Check if you have served assets cached by your web server. If so clear them.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem arises because of the cache in the browser. I have faced this problem many times. What is usually do is append an extra query string with javascript source link like this,

```
<script src="localhost/your_project_folder/index.js?v=1"></script>
```

See if this solves your problem.